# Linq query to count child records through self-join

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have two tables Categories and Category_names accordingly.

My Categories table is hierarchial parent-child table with following fields:

Id: bigint PK
ParentId: bigint

While my Category_names table has following field:

Id: bigint, PK
category_id: bigint, FK
labguage_id: bigint, FK
title: string

My challenge is to get count of child records (which are number of child categories) per each parent record, and doing it through linq query.

I have barely done something like, joining two tables and storing them in CTE (Common Table Expression) and then self-joining to that CTE, in ordeer to have two columns of category titles related to each other throgh parent-child relationship and then groupby and count the child records on MySQL.

My CTE query n MySQL is as follows:

```
WITH 
    cte 
AS
(
    SELECT c.parent_id, c.id, ct.language_id, ct.title, count(*)
    FROM tapoyrendb.categories c
    JOIN tapoyrendb.category_translations ct 
    ON (c.id=ct.category_id)
    WHERE ct.language_id = 1
    group by c.parent_id, c.id, ct.language_id, ct.title
)
SELECT ParCTE.id as ParentId, ParCTE.title as ParentTitle, count(*) -- CatCTE.id as CategoryId, CatCTE.title as CategoryTitle -- , /*count(*),*/ count(*) /*, count(CatCTE.id)*/ -- , count(parent_id)
FROM cte ParCTE
left JOIN cte CatCTE
on ParCTE.id=CatCTE.parent_id
WHERE CatCTE.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP by ParCTE.id, ParCTE.title;
```

Now I want to reproducethe same result through Linq query, despite I have faced with some discussion regarding imposibilities of CTE usage through Linq query.

Could you please advice.

Best regards,

Comment: If you interested, I can show how to do that via third party extension.

Comment: I am curious about linq version if really.

Comment: Do you think only EF can translate LINQ? [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Subquery version of my SQL query is as follows:

SELECT c.parent_id, count(*),
(SELECT title FROM tapoyrendb.category_translations as ct where language_id = 1 and ct.category_id = c.parent_id LIMIT 1) as name
FROM tapoyrendb.categories as c
group by c.parent_id